# How to use correclty pyprind with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Currently I am using [pyprind](https://github.com/rasbt/pyprind), a library that implements a progress bar:

```
#Compute training time elapsed
pbar = pyprind.ProgBar(45, width=120, bar_char='█')
for _ in range(45):
    #Fiting
    clf = SVC().fit(X_train, y_train)
    pbar.update()
#End of bar
```

However, I do not know if that is the correct way to use the `pbar`, since I guess I am fitting 45 times `clf`. Thus, how should I use correctly `pbar`?.

Comment: you cannot monitor the progress of the fitting of one SVM model, because all you do is calling the `fit` function and it will not tell you how much progress it has made so far.

Comment: @cel I think he's not trying to monitor the fitting of SVM model, its just the for loop iterations which the library looks at and updates the bar.

Comment: @hashcode55, mhm, could be. Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used `pyprind` but I have used `progressbar`. Just install it using-

```
pip install progressbar
```

And then -

```
from progressbar import ProgressBar
pbar = ProgressBar()
for x in pbar(range(45)):
    clf = SVC().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have problems installing it... I will test them right now, hold on!, thanks!

Comment: I finally have time for trying this solution. However, I believe it is still fitting 45 times.... it taked nearly 2:00 min to finish.... any idea of how to proceed?. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want more information regarding the learning process you can use `vebose` flag for that:

```
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
clf = SVC(verbose =True)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Output:

```
optimization finished, #iter = 12
obj = -1.253423, rho = 0.000003
nSV = 4, nBSV = 0
Total nSV = 4
```